# Print tomcat version and path

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a requirement to print the base dirctory of tomcat in which it is installed using java. 
my tomcat is installed in `c:\apache-tomcat\`.

In other words I want to print the `catalina.home` directorty using Java.
    System.out.println("print tomcat directory");

Comment: What is the question here? If you know that Tomcat is installed at `C:\apache-tomcat`, wouldn't `System.out.println("C:\\apache-tomcat")` be sufficient? And where do you intend to run this code - in a standalone client or in Tomcat itself?

Comment: In what context are you asking this question?

Comment: i dont want t hard code the path. i shud be automatically taken and processed

Comment: Yes, but what's the context? Why and where do you need this information? Experience learns that this kind of information need is after all either utterly unnecessary or can be solved in a much better way. For example, do you want an absolute path to store uploaded files or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("catalina.home"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get server info using this url - `http://localhost:8080/manager/text/serverinfo` command - [Manager Commands.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html).